# How to deal with nan values when using multinomial.pmf from scipy.stats?

Tags: performance, numpy, scipy, statistics, precision

Running a small experiment, I noticed that if the sum of the parameters that are passed to multinomial.pmf are even slightly above 1, then the return value is nan.

See the example below:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import multinomial as multi_s


def safe_multi(x, params):
    params_sum = params.sum()
    safe_params = params / params_sum if params_sum > 1 else params
    return multi_s.pmf(x, sum(x), safe_params)


params1 = np.array(
    [0.21310660657549002, 0.21310660657549002, 0.21310660657549002,
     2.8699968847179538e-06, 0.0023286820110742764, 2.8699968847179538e-06,
     0.0023286820110742764, 2.8699968847179538e-06, 2.8699968847179538e-06,
     0.0023258120141895593, 0.0016006555371205703, 0.0023258120141895593,
     0.0016006555371205703, 0.04333851102588555, 0.04333851102588555,
     0.04333851102588555, 0.04333851102588555, 0.04333851102588555,
     0.04333851102588555, 0.04333851102588555, 0.04333851102588555,
     0.0007251564770689873, 0.0007251564770689873, 7.377915317967555e-27,
     7.377915317967555e-27])

params2 = np.array(
    [0.3333333333333332, 0.3333333333333332, 0.3333333333333332,
     2.931077467598623e-93, 6.532951191692606e-25, 1.4080539652716124e-224,
     6.532951191692606e-25, 1.4080539652716124e-224, 1.4080539652716124e-224,
     6.532951191692606e-25, 6.532951191692606e-25, 6.532951191692606e-25,
     6.532951191692606e-25, 3.5127398105835854e-17, 3.5127398105835854e-17,
     3.5127398105835854e-17, 3.5127398105835854e-17, 3.5127398105835854e-17,
     3.5127398105835854e-17, 3.5127398105835854e-17, 3.5127398105835854e-17,
     7.860388790608641e-191, 7.860388790608641e-191, 2.931077467598623e-93,
     2.931077467598623e-93])

samples = np.array(
    [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])

result1_scipy = multi_s.pmf(samples, samples.sum(), params1)
result2_scipy = multi_s.pmf(samples, samples.sum(), params2)
print(result1_scipy, result2_scipy)
print(params1.sum(), params2.sum())

print('-----------------')

result1_scipy_sum = multi_s.pmf(samples, samples.sum(), params1 / params1.sum())
result2_scipy_sum = multi_s.pmf(samples, samples.sum(), params2 / params2.sum())
print(result1_scipy_sum, result2_scipy_sum)
print((params1 / params1.sum()).sum(), (params2 / params2.sum()).sum())

print('-----------------')

result1 = safe_multi(samples, params1)
result2 = safe_multi(samples, params2)
print(result1, result2)
```

With the output:

```
nan 0.22222222222222202
1.0000000000000002 0.9999999999999999
-----------------
0.058068684987554825 nan
0.9999999999999998 1.0000000000000002
-----------------
0.058068684987554825 0.22222222222222202
```

Is there a better way I can deal with the numerical overflow that can occur from the parameters? My safe_multi() wrapper seems to do the trick, but I am interested in the best practices of dealing with this.

EDIT: I found an example, shown below, that seems to always return nan despite the parameters summing to 1.

```
c = np.array(
    [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])

params = np.array(
    [0.02702702702702703, 0.02702702702702703, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.04054054054054054, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.06756756756756757,
     0.0945945945945946, 0.06756756756756757, 0.06756756756756757,
     0.04054054054054054, 0.04054054054054054, 0.06756756756756757,
     0.06756756756756757, 0.013513513513513514, 0.013513513513513514, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.04054054054054054, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.013513513513513514, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.04054054054054054, 0.013513513513513514,
     0.013513513513513514, 0.013513513513513514, 0.013513513513513514, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.0, 0.013513513513513514, 0.013513513513513514, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.02702702702702703, 0.02702702702702703, 0.013513513513513514,
     0.013513513513513514, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.013513513513513514, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.013513513513513514, 0.013513513513513514, 0.013513513513513514,
     0.013513513513513514, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.013513513513513514,
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.013513513513513514, 0.013513513513513514, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])

print(multi_s.pmf(c, c.sum(), params))
print(multi_s.pmf(c, c.sum(), params / params.sum()))
print(params.sum())
```

Output:

```
nan
nan
1.0
```

Having analyzed the scipy code, it seems that the culprit is on line 3012 of _multivariate.py:

```
p[..., -1] = 1. - p[..., :-1].sum(axis=-1)
```

This line ensures that the parameters sum to 1 by setting the last parameter to an appropriate value. In the example above, this adds an extremely small negative value for the last parameter which then gets flagged as a problem down the road. To ensure that this condition is satisfied, would it not be possible to divide by the sum of the parameters as opposed to performing subtraction?

Comment: Until the scipy function is modified to allow a little bit of "slop" in the sum, your `safe_multi` function is probably a reasonable work-around.  I suggest that you report this issue over on the [scipy github site](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues); click the green "New issue" button to get started.  Include your example in the issue--it nicely demonstrates why the scipy code should probably allow for a little imprecision in the sum of `p`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Hi Warren, thanks for your response! I was contemplating doing this and I think that's a great suggestion. Also, I updated my question to include a case that seems to defy my work-around.

Answer (score 0):

The nan values are introduced by validity checks in the pmf() method. The pmf() method (as well as logpmf()) wraps _logpmf(), which calculates the log probability mass function without any validity checks. If you trust the your inputs and want to avoid the nan values you could directly use multinomial._logpmf() instead:

```
def multinomial_without_checks(x, params):
    return np.exp(multi_s._logpmf(x, sum(x), params))
```

Running this on the example from your edit gives the expected result:

```
c = np.array(
[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])

params = np.array(
    [0.02702702702702703, 0.02702702702702703, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.04054054054054054, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.06756756756756757,
     0.0945945945945946, 0.06756756756756757, 0.06756756756756757,
     0.04054054054054054, 0.04054054054054054, 0.06756756756756757,
     0.06756756756756757, 0.013513513513513514, 0.013513513513513514, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.04054054054054054, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.013513513513513514, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.04054054054054054, 0.013513513513513514,
     0.013513513513513514, 0.013513513513513514, 0.013513513513513514, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.0, 0.013513513513513514, 0.013513513513513514, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.02702702702702703, 0.02702702702702703, 0.013513513513513514,
     0.013513513513513514, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.013513513513513514, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.013513513513513514, 0.013513513513513514, 0.013513513513513514,
     0.013513513513513514, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.013513513513513514,
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.013513513513513514, 0.013513513513513514, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])

print(multinomial_without_checks(c, params))
```

With the output:

```
0.02702702702702703
```